# Logstash support for Crate DB

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc, cratedb

I'm trying to import data from Crate DB(https://crate.io) to logstash using logstash jdbc input plugin. But I'm getting this error.

```
"LoadError: no such file to load -- sequel/adapters/crate"
```

I've included crate DB driver in configuration with jdbc_driver_library parameter.
Does logstash supports Crate DB, any examples?

Answer (score 0):

cratedb is not officially supported by logstash.